# LinearLayouts position themselves on (0,0) coordinates

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I am starting with Android Studio and encountered, probably trivial, problem with LinearLayouts.

When I run the application on emulator, both of my LinearLayouts move into the top left corner - therefor (0,0) coordinates.

Of all the possibilities I have, I can't find a solution. Studio maybe knows this might be happening and says that I should "add vertical/horizontal constraints" because pushing the layout on a device may cause the widgets to change position. However I am unable to decipher what precisely I should type to change it.

Here is the code, it's a simple calculator on which i hope to get a hang of the basics.

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.powerpes.kalkulacka.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="306dp"
        android:layout_height="360dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="27dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="135dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoC"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="C"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoDel"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Del"
                android:textSize="24sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoSqrt"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text=" √"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoPlusminus"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+/-"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko7"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="7"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko8"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="8"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko9"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="9"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoLomeno"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="/"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko4"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="4"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="4" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko5"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="5"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                tools:text="5" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko6"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="6"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoKrat"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="*"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko1"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="1"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko2"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="2"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko3"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoMinus"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="-"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitko0"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoCarka"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="."
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoPlus"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="+"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/tlacitkoRovno"
                android:layout_width="300dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:text="="
                android:textSize="30sp" />

        </TableRow>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="330dp"
        android:layout_height="105dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2"

        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp">

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cislo1"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="NaN"
                android:textAlignment="viewEnd" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/znamenko"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="..."
                android:textAlignment="center" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/cislo2"
                android:layout_width="135dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="NaN"
                android:textAlignment="viewStart" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/obrazovka"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="0"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </TableRow>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>`
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with `LinearLayout` but with `ConstraintLayout`. See this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html#constraints-overview).

> When you drop a view into the Layout Editor, it stays where you leave it even if it has no constraints. However, this is only to make editing easier; if a view has no constraints when you run your layout on a device, it is drawn at position [0,0] (the top-left corner).

You will need to constrain the children of `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll look into that